# Prevent user from using internet

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I have created a user with "Connect to wireless and ethernet networks" unchecked, but the user can still access internet wireless.

I have tried to remove nm-applet from the users startup programs, but the user can still run nm-applet without sudo.

This seems strange. Can anyone help me?

Ubuntu version 10.04

Answer (score 2):

If the network connection is set as a *System Connection*, as is the default, the connection is initiated by the system as soon as the signal is available.

Uncheck the System Connection flag on the connection.